# Why use a legacy api for a Firebase FCM notifications sample?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the impetus for the author of https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js Line 74 to use a [Legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm)?

Put another way, is it possible to use Firebase FCM [non-legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: I think the legacy method is used to allow sending same message to multiple tokens. `send()` support one token only for sending to device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked with the author of that sample. Back when the sample was created, what is now called the legacy API, was the best API available.

When the new v1 API was released we looked into upgrading the sample to use that. But (as Umar commented) since the new API no longer support sending to multiple tokens with one call, that upgrade got deprioritized after some other tasks.

I recommend that you file a bug on the Github repo, to get the sample updated to use the latest API. I'd also recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to get "sending to multiple tokens in one call" back into the new FCM API, since it seems like a rather useful feature.

**Update**

It seems that so-called multi-cast send operations are coming to the V1 API. From an [#AskFirebase video about FCM](https://youtu.be/ltm9EWpV124?t=4m42s):

> We are planning to add a multicast feature to HTTP V1 that will allow you to send to multiple tokens in a single API request.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Submitted an issue to the author in Github repo of Firebase. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/410